# Alternative to timer_t in macOS

Tags: linux, osx, c, macintosh, ios

We are porting a linux app to macOS / iOS

The app uses a timer wheel and timer_t type. This type is not defined in time.h class of macOS as described in:

[why is "timer_t" defined in "time.h" on Linux but not OS X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194480/why-is-timer-t-defined-in-time-h-on-linux-but-not-os-x)

Also the methods timer_create(), timer_settime() and timer_delete() are not defined.

This is the class that I'm porting: https://github.com/OpenOverlayRouter/oor/blob/testing/oor/lib/timers.c

We found that maybe we can do this with NSTimer and Objective-C but I would like to do in C.

Can we do it in C? Which kernel libraries should we use?

Thanks

Comment: What system calls use this `timer_t` type, and what does the code use them for?

Comment: We use it in a timer wheel algorithm
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867621/efficient-timer-algorithm

Comment: I thought you said you were porting an application to macOS, but you're asking about how to port a library to allow you to _not_ port the application. Am I right?

Comment: You're going to have to implement `timer_settime` on macOS, or rewrite that library to instead use some other timer callback scheme; maybe see how `libevent` or such implements timers on *BSD systems?

Comment: Yes, I have to implement timer_settime, timer_create, timer_delete and timer_t type, or search another way to provide the same function... @thrig

Comment: I changed the question. I think that now it's more clear. @Kusalananda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking with Apple Support:

The most obvious candidate here is [dispatch timer sources](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_source_create.3.html).

Now I'm working in other section of that project, after implementing the timers section I'll post more information about that if I found something interesting.

Comment: Any news? I understand that `timer_create()` and family are timer functions from the POSIX *realtime* library; I'm not sure libdispatch would be the most obvious candidate for anything realtime?

Comment: @RJVB crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807302/create-c-timer-in-macos/52905687#52905687